# "buildSelect" function code in q/kdb generates error

Tags: python-3.x, kdb

The "buildSelect" function provided in this white paper generates error when I try to apply it to a select statement.

```
tidy:{ssr/[;("\"~~";"~~\"");("";"")] $[","=first x;1_x;x]};
strBrk:{y,(";" sv x),z};
//replace k representation with equivalent q keyword
kreplace:{[x] $[`=qval:.q?x;x;"~~",string[qval],"~~"]};
funcK:{$[0=t:type x;.z.s each x;t<100h;x;kreplace x]};
//replace eg ,`FD`ABC`DEF with "enlist`FD`ABC`DEF"
ereplace:{"~~enlist",(.Q.s1 first x),"~~"};
ereptest:{((0=type x) & (1=count x) & (11=type first x)) | ((11=type x)
&(1=count x))};
funcEn:{$[ereptest x;ereplace x;0=type x;.z.s each x;x]};
basic:{tidy .Q.s1 funcK funcEn x};
addbraks:{"(",x,")"};
//where clause needs to be a list of where clauses, so if only one where
clause need to enlist.
stringify:{$[(0=type x) & 1=count x;"enlist ";""],basic x};
//if a dictionary apply to both, keys and values
ab:{$[(0=count x) | -1=type x;.Q.s1 x;99=type x;(addbraks stringify key x
),"!",stringify value x;stringify x]};
inner:{[x]
 idxs:2 3 4 5 6 inter ainds:til count x;
 x:@[x;idxs;'[ab;eval]];
 if[6 in idxs;x[6]:ssr/[;("hopen";"hclose");("iasc";"idesc")] x[6]];
 //for select statements within select statements
 x[1]:$[-11=type x 1;x 1;[idxs,:1;.z.s x 1]];
 x:@[x;ainds except idxs;string];
 x[0],strBrk[1_x;"[";"]"]
 };
buildSelect:{[x]
inner parse x
};
```

Got the following error message when applying buildSelect to a simple select statement:

ERROR: 'length 
(incompatible lengths (different lengths of operands for synchronized operation or table columns lengths are not the same)

Comment: Link of the whitepaper https://code.kx.com/v2/wp/parse_trees_and_functional_forms.pdf

Comment: What is the command that returns the error? We use buildSelect frequently and works fine.

Comment: update idx:til count clock from `clock

Comment: Where clock is a table of timestamps. The above code works fine. But it generates error when I try: selectBuild "update idx:til count clock from `clock"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the select statement you are providing to the `buildSelect` function. I fyou remove the back tick the function now runs.

```
q)buildSelect"update idx:til count clock from `clock"
'length
  [3]  /home/lholmes/qsqltofunctional.q:23: inner:
     if[6 in idxs;x[6]:ssr/[;("hopen";"hclose");("iasc";"idesc")] x[6]];
     x[1]:$[-11=type x 1;x 1;[idxs,:1;.z.s x 1]];
         ^
     x:@[x;ainds except idxs;string];
q))\
q)buildSelect"update idx:til count clock from clock"
"![clock;();0b;(enlist`idx)!enlist (til;(count;`clock))]"
```

This will produce the following:

```
q)t:([]time:10#.z.p)
q)update idx:i from t
time                          idx
---------------------------------
2019.06.19D08:39:15.720370000 0
2019.06.19D08:39:15.720370000 1
2019.06.19D08:39:15.720370000 2
2019.06.19D08:39:15.720370000 3
2019.06.19D08:39:15.720370000 4
2019.06.19D08:39:15.720370000 5
2019.06.19D08:39:15.720370000 6
2019.06.19D08:39:15.720370000 7
2019.06.19D08:39:15.720370000 8
2019.06.19D08:39:15.720370000 9
```

Hope this helps, if you have any additional questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, it was indeed the back tick that creates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For your clock table you dont even need command `selectBuild`. Q function `parse` will do the job. Simplify your code be leveraging virtual column `i`

```
parse "update idx:i from clock"
```

modified output:

```
![`clock; (); 0b; enlist[`idx]!enlist `i]
```

also, I recommend using

```
clock: update idx:i from clock
```

instead of

```
update idx:i from `clock
```

as the buildSelect does not handle the second form. Also, your code will run with a local clock table.

Comment: Thanks Ferenc. I understand the parse function. I was simply trying to test how buildSelect works. Will follow your coding advice in the future!

Comment: For more Q coding advice you may want to take a look at my two articles:  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/lists-python-q-side-by-side-ferenc-bodon-ph-d-/ and https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/data-analysis-example-python-q-ferenc-bodon-ph-d-/

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work is that `buildSelect` is only expecting to be passed in tables by value in the parse tree, i.e., the element at the index 1 is expected to be an atomic symbol, not an enlist symbol, which is the case for parsing updates by name.

```
q)parse "update col1:val from tab"
!
`tab
()
0b
(,`col1)!,`val
q)parse "update col1:val from `tab"
!
,`tab
()
0b
(,`col1)!,`val
```

This causes issues at the following line in `inner`

```
x[1]:$[-11=type x 1;x 1;[idxs,:1;.z.s x 1]];
```

A more robust buildSelect can be made by the following adjustment

```
inner:{[x]
    idxs:2 3 4 5 6 inter ainds:til count x;
    x:@[x;idxs;'[ab;eval]];
    if[6 in idxs;x[6]:ssr/[;("hopen";"hclose");("iasc";"idesc")] x[6]];
    //for select statements within select statements
    x[1]:$[-11=type x 1;x 1;$[11h=type x 1;[idxs,:1;"`",string first x 1];[idxs,:1;.z.s x 1]]];
    x:@[x;ainds except idxs;string];
    x[0],strBrk[1_x;"[";"]"]
    };
```

Which will then allow for the following

```
q)buildSelect "update col1:val from `tab"
"![`tab;();0b;(enlist`col1)!enlist`val]"
q)buildSelect "update col1:val from tab"
"![tab;();0b;(enlist`col1)!enlist`val]"
```